# How to assign multiple values to ASP.NET pages from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page which is developed in ASP.NET and C#. On this particular page the logged in users can see who their manager is and the manager contact details etc. The details are being retrieved from a database. I am using the following code

```
protected string ManagerData()
{
    string UsrName = User.Identity.Name;
    string mName;
    string mNum;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ManagerName,ManagerNumber from Managers where UserName=@UserName"))
        {
            SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("UserName", UsrName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(para);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                mName = reader.GetString(0);
                mNum = reader.GetString(1);
            }
        }
    }
    return //How would i return both of the string
}
```

It returns the values. To display them I use the following code

```
<h5>Your Manager is:<%:ManagerData() %> </h5>
```

But if I do

```
<h5>Your Managers Number is:<%:ManagerData() %> </h5>
```

It returns the name of Manager in both cases. So my question is should I write a separate method to get the managers number or is there a way to return two strings from the above method?

Thanks in advance for all your help and support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parameter to the **ManagerData** function whether you need **name** or **number**.

```
protected string ManagerData(String sValue)
{
    string UsrName = User.Identity.Name;
    string mName;
    string mNum;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ManagerName,ManagerNumber from Managers where UserName=@UserName"))
        {
            SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("UserName", UsrName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(para);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                mName = reader.GetString(0);
                mNum = reader.GetString(1);
            }
        }
    }

    if(sValue = "name")
     return mName;
    else
     return mNum    
}

<h5>Your Manager is:<%:ManagerData("name") %> </h5>

<h5>Your Managers Number is:<%:ManagerData("number") %> </h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Returning multiple values

You can use "out" parameters for getting multiple values. for eg.

```
   Public string mName;
   Public string mNum;
        protected void ManagerData(out string mName,out string mNum)
    {
        string UsrName = User.Identity.Name;
        string mName;
        string mNum;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ManagerName,ManagerNumber from Managers where UserName=@UserName"))
            {
                SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("UserName", UsrName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(para);
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    mName = reader.GetString(0);
                    mNum = reader.GetString(1);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

on Source page

```
  <h5>Your Manager is:<%= mName %></h5>
     <h5>Your Manager is:<%= mNum %></h5>
```

After this function executes you can have values of mName and mNum.